# PHPWord Table gridspan and Vmerge

Tags: php, phpword

I want to get that in phpword

```
------------------------
|     |                | 
|-----------------------
|     |                |
------------------------
|     |     |     |    |                
|-----------------------
```

but I keep getting

```
----------------------
|     |              | 
|---------------------------------
|     |              |     |     |
----------------------------------
```

I am familiar with the fact that I have to somehow incorporate:

```
array('gridSpan' => 3) ($table->addCell(15000, array('gridSpan' => 3))->addText(htmlspecialchars('text'), $fontTitle);)
```

but I can't figure out the correct syntax to actually get the table to look the way I want it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out,

you have to add

```
$cell5->getStyle()->setGridSpan(3);
```